# How to run the compiled JS files from TypeScript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-chrome

I am very new with TypeScript and I want to run the compiled files in the web but I am getting some errors in the browser

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "src/out",
        "rootDir": "src/",
        "removeComments": true,
        "paths": {
            "@interfaces/*": ["src/interfaces/*"],
            "@plugins/*": ["src/plugins/*"],
        },
        "types": ["node", "jquery"]
    }
}
```

This is the first 3 lines from the compiled file

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var sweetAlert = require("src/plugins/third.party/sweetalert2.js");
```

and the errors that the browser shows me is that the word "exports" and "require" are not defined

my typescript version is "3.6.4"

Comment: Are you using webpack? If not, you probably should be since there are standard setups for browser.

Comment: I am not using webpack because I do not know it, could you give me an example, please?

Comment: My earlier answer was off-base so I deleted it, but the https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html page will probably hold the key.  I'd try `module` next.

Comment: I agree with @user2740650 that `module` may be key. Try using `ES5`. As for webpack, it is huge, so just look up "webpack tutorial". Might be a little intimidating at first glance, but it's actually pretty simple to find a recipe that works for standard setups.

Comment: Try [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&module=5#code/FDCWFsAcHsCcBcAEBvRANRBfRAzW1xEAiAZwIFN4ALUAOwHMBaOZ682IgbmAGNpayAG3IA6QdHoAKNAEpOQA).  Under the config menu with module set to None, I get JS that looks like yours.  If I change it to ES2015, I get JS that should work in modern browsers.  Beware that older browsers won't understand it, which is where a tool like webpack and/or babel comes in handy.

Comment: all the modules options does not works for me, I'll try to use webpack, thanks a lot